# combinational optimization resource

Tags: algorithm

Hi algorithm fans! I have problem to solve which is classified as combinational optimization problem. I do not have any background about this technique. Does anyone know any source, tutorial, article where I can learn this technique?

Comment: Combinational optimization consists of a broad range of problems, each with their own solution, if any. Unless you tell us which problem you are facing, we can't really help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From wikipedia :

*In applied mathematics and theoretical computer science, combinatorial optimization is a topic that consists of finding an optimal object from a finite set of objects.*

The finite set of objects can be really big and it would take an infinite time to your program to find the solution.

For most of these problems there is no 'technique'.

I would advise reading the wikipedia article on [combinatorial optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization), then look at links such as [complexity therory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) (and [complexity class P NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) ), and very common examples such as the [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman_problem).

Hope it helps